# Unable to register the client with eureka server (The is no security in the classpath)

Tags: netflix-eureka

Unable to register the client with eureka server (The is no security in the classpath)

```
pom.xml (server)
spring boot version 2.0.3.RELEASE

org.springframework.cloud
spring-cloud-dependencies
Finchley.RELEASE

org.springframework.cloud
spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server

application.yml (server)
spring:
application:
name: eureka-service

server:
port: 8302

eureka:
client:
register-with-eureka: false
fetch-registry: false
server:
wait-time-in-ms-when-sync-empty: 0

The eureka server started fine and can be accessed at http://localhost:8302/

pom.xml (client)
spring boot version 2.0.3.RELEASE

org.springframework.cloud
spring-cloud-dependencies
Finchley.RELEASE

org.springframework.cloud
spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client

application.yml (client)
spring:
application:
name: stock-service

server:
port: 8301

eureka:
client:
register-with-eureka: false
fetch-registry: false
service-url:
default-zone: http://localhost:8302/

instance:
hostname: localhost
```

When running the client application, getting the following stack trace

> 2018-07-09 13:42:40.279 INFO 265144 --- [trap-executor-0] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
>       2018-07-09 13:42:50.123 INFO 265144 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : Disable delta property : false
>       2018-07-09 13:42:50.123 INFO 265144 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : Single vip registry refresh property : null
>       2018-07-09 13:42:50.123 INFO 265144 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : Force full registry fetch : false
>       2018-07-09 13:42:50.123 INFO 265144 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : Application is null : false
>       2018-07-09 13:42:50.123 INFO 265144 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : Registered Applications size is zero : true
>       2018-07-09 13:42:50.123 INFO 265144 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : Application version is -1: true
>       2018-07-09 13:42:50.123 INFO 265144 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
>       2018-07-09 13:42:52.128 ERROR 265144 --- [freshExecutor-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient : Request execution error
>
> com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>       at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
>       at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
>       at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
>       at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
>       at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
>       at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
>       at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:509) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
>       at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.getApplicationsInternal(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:194) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
>       at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.getApplications(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:165) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
>       at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) [eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
>       at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
>       at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) [eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
>       at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) [eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
>       at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:118) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
>       at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:79) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
>       at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) [eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
>       at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) [eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
>       at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:120) [eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
>       at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) [eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
>       at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) [eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
>       at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) [eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
>       at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) [eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
>       at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1051) [eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
>       at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:965) [eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
>       at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.refreshRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1471) [eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
>       at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$CacheRefreshThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1438) [eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_171]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_171]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_171]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_171]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
>       Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>       at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
>       at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
>       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
>       at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
>       at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
>       at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:134) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:118) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
>       at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:173) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
>       ... 30 common frames omitted
>
> 2018-07-09 13:42:52.128 WARN 265144 --- [freshExecutor-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient : Request execution failed with message: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>       2018-07-09 13:42:52.129 ERROR 265144 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : DiscoveryClient_STOCK-SERVICE/del1-lhp-n02547.synapse.com:stock-service:8301 - was unable to refresh its cache! status = Cannot execute request on any known server
>
> com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
>       at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
>       at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
>       at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
>       at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
>       at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
>       at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1051) [eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
>       at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:965) [eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
>       at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.refreshRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1471) [eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
>       at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$CacheRefreshThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1438) [eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_171]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_171]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_171]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_171]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your client i.e **stock service's** `application.yml`. You need to change it as mentioned here.

Step 1: Remove below properties from application.yml

`eureka:
  client:
   register-with-eureka: false
   fetch-registry: false 
   service-url:
     default-zone: http://localhost:8302/`

instance:
hostname: localhost

Step 2: add this in application.yml

`eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8302/eureka/`

This may resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

- the current thread.

You should also change the below property from false to true in your client application.yml file-

eureka:
  client:
    **register-with-eureka: true**

It seems like, in your configuration for client it is **false**.